# Why is the PDF generation using make.bat generated by Doxygen (LateX, refman.tex) on Windows not working?

Tags: pdf-generation, doxygen, pdflatex, code-documentation

I'm trying to generate LateX based code documentation using doxygen and using the make.bat created by doxygen to generate from LateX (refman.tex) a PDF.

**Installations:**
Operating System: Windows
Software:

- Doxygen 1.9.7
- MiKTeX 23.4
- Graphviz 8.0.5

**Powershell script:**

```
doxygen $configurationFile
$latextOutputDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($exportDirectory, "latex")
cd $latextOutputDirectory 
Invoke-Expression -Command ".\make.bat"
```

**make.bat generated by doxygen:**

```
pushd %~dp0
if not %errorlevel% == 0 goto :end

set ORG_LATEX_CMD=%LATEX_CMD%
set ORG_MKIDX_CMD=%MKIDX_CMD%
set ORG_BIBTEX_CMD=%BIBTEX_CMD%
set ORG_LATEX_COUNT=%LATEX_COUNT%
set ORG_MANUAL_FILE=%MANUAL_FILE%
if "X"%LATEX_CMD% == "X" set LATEX_CMD=pdflatex
if "X"%MKIDX_CMD% == "X" set MKIDX_CMD=makeindex
if "X"%BIBTEX_CMD% == "X" set BIBTEX_CMD=bibtex
if "X"%LATEX_COUNT% == "X" set LATEX_COUNT=8
if "X"%MANUAL_FILE% == "X" set MANUAL_FILE=refman

del /s /f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl %MANUAL_FILE%.pdf


%LATEX_CMD% %MANUAL_FILE%
echo ----
%MKIDX_CMD% %MANUAL_FILE%.idx
echo ----
%LATEX_CMD% %MANUAL_FILE%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=%LATEX_COUNT%
:repeat
set content=X
for /F "tokens=*" %%T in ( 'findstr /C:"Rerun LaTeX" %MANUAL_FILE%.log' ) do set content="%%~T"
if !content! == X for /F "tokens=*" %%T in ( 'findstr /C:"Rerun to get cross-references right" %MANUAL_FILE%.log' ) do set content="%%~T"
if !content! == X for /F "tokens=*" %%T in ( 'findstr /C:"Rerun to get bibliographical references right" %MANUAL_FILE%.log' ) do set content="%%~T"
if !content! == X goto :skip
set /a count-=1
if !count! EQU 0 goto :skip

echo ----
%LATEX_CMD% %MANUAL_FILE%
goto :repeat
:skip
endlocal
%MKIDX_CMD% %MANUAL_FILE%.idx
%LATEX_CMD% %MANUAL_FILE%

@REM reset environment
popd
set LATEX_CMD=%ORG_LATEX_CMD%
set ORG_LATEX_CMD=
set MKIDX_CMD=%ORG_MKIDX_CMD%
set ORG_MKIDX_CMD=
set BIBTEX_CMD=%ORG_BIBTEX_CMD%
set ORG_BIBTEX_CMD=
set MANUAL_FILE=%ORG_MANUAL_FILE%
set ORG_MANUAL_FILE=
set LATEX_COUNT=%ORG_LATEX_COUNT%
set ORG_LATEX_COUNT=

:end
```

**Powershell output:**

```
C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>pushd C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1\

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>if not 0 == 0 goto :end

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>set ORG_LATEX_CMD=

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>set ORG_MKIDX_CMD=

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>set ORG_BIBTEX_CMD=

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>set ORG_LATEX_COUNT=

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>set ORG_MANUAL_FILE=

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>if "X" == "X" set LATEX_CMD=pdflatex

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>if "X" == "X" set MKIDX_CMD=makeindex

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>if "X" == "X" set BIBTEX_CMD=bibtex

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>if "X" == "X" set LATEX_COUNT=8

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>if "X" == "X" set MANUAL_FILE=refman

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>del /s /f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log 

*.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf

Deleted file - C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1\refman.aux
Deleted file - C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1\refman.toc
Deleted file - C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1\refman.idx
Deleted file - C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1\refman.log
Deleted file - C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1\refman.out

C:\src\project\docs\export\code\latex1>pdflatex refman
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(refman.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\array-2016-10-06.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty) (doxygen.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\alltt.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\verbatim.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)) (longtable_doxygen.sty)(tabu_doxygen.sty(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/varwidth\varwidth.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\tabularx.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\multicol.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hanging\hanging.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\adjustbox.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex)))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\adjcalc.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\trimclip.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/collectbox\collectbox.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/adjustbox\tc-pdftex.def))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/stackengine\stackengine.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listofitems\listofitems.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/listofitems\listofitems.tex)))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/alphalph\alphalph.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ulem\ulem.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\makeidx.sty)
 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/wasysym\wasysym.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\helvet.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\courier.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/changepage\changepage.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tocloft\tocloft.sty)
Writing index file refman.idx
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/newunicodechar\newunicodechar.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty)))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\backref.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty))))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\ltcaption.sty))
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoc\etoc.sty)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/psnfss\t1phv.fd)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file refman.aux.
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
No file refman.toc.
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd)
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/wasysym\uwasy.fd)
[1{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}{C:/Use
rs/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}]
(namespaces.tex

LaTeX Warning: Reference `namespace_x' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `namespace_x_1_1_y' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `namespace_x_1_1_y_1_1_l_d_a' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.
```

**Errors:**

- No file refman.aux
- No file refman.toc
- LaTeX Warning: Reference `namespace_x' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.

Comment: To be able to say something sensible we need a Minimal Working Example (MWE) consisting of the used doxygen settings (i.e. the ones different from the default settings: `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and the source code generating the problem so we can run the MWE and see what the problem is. Does this problem also occur when running in a "DOS" shell and thus not in a "PowerShell"?

Comment: @KJ The `namespaces.tex` files is a file generated by doxygen based on the sources, therefore I requested a MWE.

Comment: @KJ we don't need a `simple.tex` but the original sources fed into doxygen (i.e. the C/Cpp/C#/Fortran ... source code). The `refman.tex` etc. are all generated by doxygen based on the sources fed into doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the code cannot be the issue, since generating the HTML based code documentation works fine. But using latex & the make.bat is not working and it doesn't make a difference using Powershell or the cmd, the error outcome is the same.

The doxygen configuration looks as follows:

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = Project
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 0.0.1
PROJECT_BRIEF          =
PROJECT_LOGO           = C://src//project//docs//automation//logo.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = C:\src\project\docs\export\code
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
CREATE_SUBDIRS_LEVEL   = 8
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
JAVADOC_BANNER         = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
PYTHON_DOCSTRING       = YES
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_SLICE  = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 5
MARKDOWN_ID_STYLE      = DOXYGEN
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
NUM_PROC_THREADS       = 1
TIMESTAMP              = NO
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
RESOLVE_UNNAMED_PARAMS = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = SYSTEM
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_HEADERFILE        = YES
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
LAYOUT_FILE            =
CITE_BIB_FILES         =
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_IF_INCOMPLETE_DOC = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_IF_UNDOC_ENUM_VAL = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LINE_FORMAT       = "at line $line of file $file"
WARN_LOGFILE           =
INPUT                  = C:\src\project\src
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
INPUT_FILE_ENCODING    =
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.l \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f18 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.ice
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                =
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             =
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE =
FORTRAN_COMMENT_AFTER  = 72
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_ADD_INC_PATHS    = YES
CLANG_OPTIONS          =
CLANG_DATABASE_PATH    =
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
IGNORE_PREFIX          =
GENERATE_HTML          = NO
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            =
HTML_FOOTER            =
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  =
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       =
HTML_COLORSTYLE        = AUTO_LIGHT
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_FEEDURL         =
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               =
HHC_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     =
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
SITEMAP_URL            =
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               =
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   =
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHG_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
FULL_SIDEBAR           = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
OBFUSCATE_EMAILS       = YES
HTML_FORMULA_FORMAT    = png
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_MACROFILE      =
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_VERSION        = MathJax_2
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        =
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       =
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       =
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     =
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  =
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         =
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
LATEX_MAKEINDEX_CMD    = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = YES
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         =
LATEX_HEADER           =
LATEX_FOOTER           =
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET =
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_EMOJI_DIRECTORY  =
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    =
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    =
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             =
MAN_LINKS              = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
XML_NS_MEMB_FILE_SCOPE = NO
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX =
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
TAGFILES               =
GENERATE_TAGFILE       =
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_COMMON_ATTR        = "fontname=Helvetica,fontsize=10"
DOT_EDGE_ATTR          = "labelfontname=Helvetica,labelfontsize=10"
DOT_NODE_ATTR          = "shape=box,height=0.2,width=0.4"
DOT_FONTPATH           =
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
DOT_UML_DETAILS        = NO
DOT_WRAP_THRESHOLD     = 17
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH    = 1
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               =
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
DIA_PATH               =
DIAFILE_DIRS           =
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      =
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      =
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  =
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
MSCGEN_TOOL            =
MSCFILE_DIRS           =
```

Generating the latex ends with

```
Patching output file 178/179
Patching output file 179/179
type lookup cache used 10860/65536 hits=24453 misses=11685
symbol lookup cache used 2423/65536 hits=13446 misses=2423
finished...
```

Comment: You wrote "In my opinion the code cannot be the issue, since generating the HTML based code documentation works fine." but the HTML generator and the LaTeX generator do slightly different things. I see you use `COMPACT_LATEX          = YES` what happens when setting `COMPACT_LATEX          = NO`? Still a MWE is necessary!!

Comment: I cannot share the code it's intellectual property. I'll try to setup a solution that has the same issues. COMPACT_LATEX = NO is resulting in the same errors. 

What concerns me is the latex output

type lookup cache used 10860/65536 hits=24453 misses=11685
symbol lookup cache used 2423/65536 hits=13446 misses=2423

Is increasing the cache maybe needed do to the size of the solution?

Comment: The mentioned cache has nothing to do with it.